# Google Cloud ML engine-Local prediction doesn't output anything (Object Detection)

Tags: google-cloud-ml, object-detection-api

I exported a custom object detection model to saved model successfully (the saved_model_cli command outputs the Signature def). In addition, when I test the model on jupyter notebook, the inference works. However, I am trying to serve this model for prediction but when I test it locally using:

`gcloud ml-engine local predict --model-dir=$LOCATION_TO_SAVED_MODEL --json-instances=$JSONFILE_CONTAINING_INPUTS`

the command outputs nothing, no errors to debug either. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There was a tensorflow version issue (was using tf 1.11 in stead of tf 1.9). Very strange that I was able to figure it out after deploying the model on cloud. Also, ideally the inference should work with any version >= tf 1.9. Not sure why it doesn't with Google's ML engine.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because the run time version should be compatible to support the tensorflow verion that you are using

Runtime version 1.13 supports TensorFlow 1.13.1 for CPU and GPU. GPUs are supported for training, but not for batch prediction or online prediction in this runtime version.

Refer to the below link to know the details about the runtime version

Visit https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/runtime-version-list

Comment: My intention with above comment was to enforce better error logging. The test command logged no errors. Secondly, an ideal case should be support of future models. For example tf 2.0 should be able to support models trained on tf 1.13.1.

Answer (score 0):

When deploying model did you specify the --runtime-version? If you didn't specify them AI Platform uses default version 1.0

https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/runtime-version-list